# SharePoint 2010 Webpart Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-designer

I created a web part and deployed it. I want to display only webpart data. I dont want to display toolbar which allow minimize, close and edit web part & title , i did set Chrome Type=None . but its not working. How can i make web part as non-configurable to users means user can see it. not configure it.

thanks

Comment: Hi, 
  ChromeType="None" is working for me.. can u put full code for this <WebPartPages:SPUserCodeWebPart...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is depend on privileges. Where you administrator you will see every web part options, but if you a anonymous user can see only title if you not set as chrome.

Comment: Which kind of site you building? Internet anonymous or intranet site?